# How to output latin characters in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, event-viewer

I have a service application that have to write information in the Windows Event Viewer. It happens that it have a version in Spanish and needs to have Latin characters in the text, so when the information is written to the Even Viewer it displays incorrectly. My .mc file is as follows:

```
; // ***** log_messages.mc *****

; // This is the header.

MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

SeverityNames=(Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
)

FacilityNames=(System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
Stubs=0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
Io=0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
)

LanguageNames=(Spanish=0x0c0a:MSG00c0a)

; // The following are message definitions.

MessageId=0x1
Severity=Informational
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=MSG_INFO
Language=Spanish
Información: %1
.

MessageId=0x2
Severity=Warning
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=MSG_WARNING
Language=Spanish
Precaución: %1
.

MessageId=0x3
Severity=Error
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=MSG_ERROR
Language=Spanish
Error: %1
.
```

When the information is displayed, for example an Information event the Latin characters are displayed incorrectly:

[image]

If someone have had this issue and could help me, thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it, the problem was when generating the .h and .rc files with mc.exe I used this parameters:

```
mc -U mymcfile.mc
```

Taking into account that the output should be in Windows in Unicode characters set, but the mc tool was taking the input as ANSI, so I add a parameter:

```
mc -u -U mymcfile.mc
```

At first it returned an error cuz the file was in ANSI, but I converted it to UNICODE and it worked fine after that. Hope this could help others...